# IOS - Connecting to bluetooth device in background periodically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device which connects to my iphone and i can perform all sorts of operations on the device. Its a tracking device and I log all sensor based data in the device. Since the device have a data limit,  I want to read data from the device once every hour and dump it into a file through the app.

Now I have gone through all the documentation from Apple and other medium blogs and stack overflow questions, but I didnt find the correct solution on how to run a process in background. Also it has to be periodic. I need something that will trigger my code once every hour and I can connect to the bluetooth device and  download the data.

I know for security reasons and for extended battery life apple doesnt support running background process infinitely. But I have to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly but basic concept is this: run a background job (which could be simple sleep call) and queue another background job before finish.

Comment: There is no way to periodically execute an app in the background on iOS.  If the device is remaining within range of your phone then it would be better to stay connected and either have the device send new data continually or send data (via a notify) when the buffer is getting full.